# Visual Studio 2019 Android Emulator not working

Tags: android, emulator, visual-studio-2019

I can get the Visual Studio 2019 Android emulator to work on one machine but not another. I have verified that the following settings are identical on both machines:

- Hardware acceleration turned on in the BIOS.
- Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform - all checked on both machines - as outlined on this page:
  [Hardware acceleration for emulator performance (Hyper-V & HAXM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration)
- Hardware DEP is available and configured as described here:
  [How to determine that hardware DEP is available and configured on your computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/912923/how-to-determine-that-hardware-dep-is-available-and-configured-on-your)
- The emulator profiles (.avd files) in Android Device Manager are the same.

I also followed suggestions from Stack Overflow posts like this one:
[Android emulator not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716572/visualstudio-android-emulator-not-starting), but none of these suggestions are working for me. I continue to see this error: Windows Hypervisor Platform error.

[image: Windows Hypervisor Platform error]

I recently installed Visual Studio 2019 on both machines so they are both brand new installs.

I am at a loss as to why it works on one machine and not the other, so is there another setting I can check for comparison?

[Windows Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OQQA.png)

Comment: I thought I should mention that both machines have Intel Core i7 processors, one has 16GB RAM, the other 24GB, both running 64 bit Windows 10 with the latest updates.

Also, I am able to create a Hyper-V virtual machine on the computer that will not run the Android emulator.

Comment: The machine that is NOT working is an i7-950
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37150/intel-core-i7-950-processor-8m-cache-3-06-ghz-4-80-gt-s-intel-qpi.html

The machine that is working has an Intel Core i7-4700MQ.
https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75117/intel-core-i7-4700mq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html 

I verified that the Hyper-V Platform is enabled using the PowerShell command suggested here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7908aa14-a9a1-43e4-ace7-bc88525d27e6/install-windows-hypervisor-platform-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Screenshots of Windows Features indicating both features are enabled would be helpful

Comment: I thought it might be helpful to add that my MOBO is a Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R Rev 2.

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-X58A-UD3R-rev-20#ov

Comment: Another post suggested I search the Xamarin Device Manager log here:
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\XamarinDeviceManager. I saw this error: emulator: WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0, which according to the post means that my processor is too old for the new Microsoft Hypervisor Platform required by the Android emulator.

Answer (score -1):

I did what is written in the following web page and stopped the Docker service at the end.

http://www.techbubbles.com/visual-studio-2019/android-emulator-setup-tip-visual-studio/