# Cannot launch an x86 Android emulator using Hyperv, but can with HAXM, why?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, android

I asked this question a few weeks ago: [Does my CPU/motherboard support VT-x?](https://superuser.com/questions/1474059/does-my-cpu-motherboard-support-vt-x).  I have a [Core I7 950](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37150/intel-core-i7-950-processor-8m-cache-3-06-ghz-4-80-gt-s-intel-qpi.html).

I am having problems running X86 Emulators on my Windows 10 PC.  When I Start an emulator in Visual Studio 2017 (or 2019) I see this:

[image]

I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows).  Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

If I uninstall Hyperv and Hyperv plaform (using Windows Features) and install Haxm then the problem goes away and everything works as expected.  However, I cannot use Docker.

The answerer of my previous question suggested that Hyperv may only work with Android on ARM based processors.  However, I have set all of this up on my new work laptop, which has an intel processor and is Windows 10 and everything works as expected.  If I run the command DOS command above on my work PC then I see this:

[image]

Notice there is no EPT/UG warning.  My work PC is [i5-8250U](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/124967/intel-core-i5-8250u-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html).

Could this have something to do with what the command prompt is saying i.e. missing EPT + UG Features? The answerer of my previous question says my CPU supports these features.  Do I need to do something in the BIOS to enable them?My research is telling me that UG is only supported on Westmere CPUs onwards.  However, my CPU is Bloomfield.

**Update**

I have disabled Hyperv on my work PC (where I have no problems) and my home PC (where I do have problems) to run the Intel CPU Identification Utility.  Here was the result of the work PC:

[image]

and here is the home PC:

[image]

I read this post here: [Visual Studio 2019 Android Emulator not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1435531/visual-studio-2019-android-emulator-not-working).  The OP has the same CPU as me and I see the same output as him when I try to run the emulator from the command line:

```
WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0
```

Comment: Use the Intel tool I suggested, after you ALL software that utilizes VT-x and then update your question.  I stand by my answer to your other question.

Comment: I know for a fact your processor supports EPT, which means it also supports Unrestricted Guest (UG), since a processor cannot support one without the other.  What is more likely than your processor not having EPT, is there is a problem with the check you are using, hence the reason for the Intel tool.

Comment: Relevant: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/virtualization-software-development/topic/277958 you might have to write your own tool to see true value of the flag.

Comment: @Ramhound, I have updated my question as requested.  Thanks.

Comment: I am 90% sure WHvGetCapability is only supported on 19H2.  However, I have confirmed that **SmepSupport** is indeed considered Unrestricted Guest (UG) based on the description of SMEP.

Comment: I am wandering if the EPT+UG warning is just a red herring.  Other posts I have read today state difficulties with the 950 (the same problem I am having).  It appears to be compatible on paper though (as you say).